# Edited: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct Bar’ from type ‘struct Bar *’

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

Edit: Code was cleaned up to avoid confuse on question.  As far as the question: I want to allocate memory of size struct Foo2.  Then allocate memory of size struct Bar and assign that location to a->b.  Afterwards I want to set a->b.x to an integer value.  This code is generated so I am looking to understand the concepts of allocating memory for structs and setting their values.

How do I access `a->b`?  I grasp that I can't set a pointer to it.

```
Error:  incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct Bar’ from
type ‘struct Bar *’?
```

Also why can I not put `typedef struct Bar` after the struct of `Foo2` without an `error: unknown type name ‘Bar’`?

```
typedef struct ForwardClassTest ForwardClassTest;
typedef struct Foo2 Foo2;
typedef struct Bar Bar;
struct ForwardClassTest {
};
struct Bar {
    int x;
};
struct Foo2 {
    Bar b;
};
int main();
  //Foo2 a
  Foo2 * a = (Foo2 *) malloc(sizeof(Foo2));
  //a=new Foo2()
  a = (Foo2*) malloc(sizeof(Foo2));
  //a.b=new Bar()
  a->b = (Bar*) malloc(sizeof(Bar));
  //a.b.x=5
  a->b.x = 5;
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Don't repeat `typedef`. The compiler heard you the first time. You told it that "Foo" is another name for "struct Foo", and that's fine. Later, you need to tell it what struct Foo looks like. But you do that just with a simple declaration: "struct Foo { int x; };", no typedef. Oh, and you're leaking memory all over the place.

Comment: `void* main(char* args[])` --> `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: The c compiler starts at the top and works its way down thus you need to put the 'Bar' declaration before 'Foo' that is why sometimes you see function declarations at the top of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there was not a complete answer @ed-heal pointed me in right direction.  I worked out solution.  The only way to do this was by adding a pointer to Bar b in Foo2.

```
typedef struct Foo2 Foo2;
typedef struct Bar Bar;
struct Bar {
    int x;
};
struct Foo2 {
    Bar *b;
};
int main(){
  Foo2 * a = (Foo2 *) malloc(sizeof(Foo2));
  a = (Foo2*) malloc(sizeof(Foo2));
  a->b = (Bar*) malloc(sizeof(Bar));
  a->b->x = 5;
  free(a);
  free(a->b);
  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. This line `Foo2 *a = (Foo2 *) malloc(sizeof(Foo2))` should be `Foo2 * a = malloc(sizeof(Foo2))`
2. The line `a->b = (Bar*) malloc(sizeof(Bar));` is not required as `b` is not a pointer
3. The stuff:

   `typedef struct ForwardClassTest ForwardClassTest;
    typedef struct Foo2 Foo2;
    typedef struct Bar Bar;
    typedef struct ForwardClassTest {`

is not required

4. This is wrong `void* main(char* args[]){` should be `int main(int, char**)` as the arguments are not used.
5. Use `free` to free the memory

Comment: So only way to accomplish a->b = * is to:

`Bar * z = (Bar*) malloc(sizeof(Bar));
a->b = *z;`

@Ed-Heal

Comment: Eh? Just fixed the bugs in your code - try that. The comments do not make any sense anyway

Comment: Where does `requestBlock` come from? Just do the corrections as mentioned above and re-read about pointers.

Comment: Comments were part of transpiled output.  I should have cleaned it up better.

Comment: part of a garbage compiler.  returns the return of a malloc.

Comment: `void main()` is also wrong. `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` or equivalent are correct.

Comment: @mch - It is tagged as C - Not C++ - otherwise you would be correct

Comment: `int main()` is only correct in C++, but not in C, but this is a minor problem, the real mistake is the `void` return value.

Comment: @mch - C compilers do allow void to be returned. It is old skool stuff. I agree it is better to return `int` and have updated the answer. But considering the rest of the code :-)

Comment: I would vote this reply up but I am too new to stack overflow.